# how to change hint text color of textinputlayout

Tags: android, colors, android-textinputlayout

Hi I am using TextInputLayout in my app. I want to set hint text color and floating label color(both focused and unfocused) to white. I have tried below code.

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:hint="Hiiiii"
android:id="@+id/edit_id">
 </android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
//hint color And Label Color in False State
<item name="android:textColorHint">@color/Color Name</item> 
<item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
//Label color in True State And Bar Color False And True State
<item name="colorAccent">@color/Color Name</item>
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/Color Name</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/Color Name</item>
</style>
```

It is working properly for lollipop but not for lower versions.How can i achieve the same in lower versions as well?

Answer (score 0):

I got answer for this. In OS versions lower than lollipop we have to set the text color as white(in my case) in the app theme. Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Give the same **style** to `Text Input Style` that you are giving to `Edittext`

```
 <!--Text Input Style-->
    <style name="styleTextInputLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorSecondary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">?android:attr/textColorSecondaryInverse</item>
    </style>


 <!--EditText-->
    <style name="styleEditText" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorSecondary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">?android:attr/textColorSecondaryInverse</item>
    </style>
```

give your respective colors to tags above

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    style="@style/styleTextInputLayout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtTextFirstName"
                        style="@style/styleEditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_5_dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_5_dp"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_first_name"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
                        android:singleLine="true" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

above code works with

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

I was facing problem with `22` version, may be there is some bug because of which Text Input ignores style provided to it.

Solution for `com.android.support:design` below `23` is:

**style.xml**

```
 <style name="styleTextInputTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColorHint">?android:attr/textColorSecondaryInverse</item>
    </style>
```

**set theme to TextInputLayout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:theme="@style/styleTextInputTextAppearance">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtTextTowerName"
                        style="@style/styleEditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_5_dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_5_dp"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_tower_name"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="textCapWords"
                        android:singleLine="true" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```